# How to convert any native app to ionic cordova plugin

Tags: android, ios, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic-native

my question is

**How i can include any native functionality like **

https://github.com/AarogyaSetu/QR-Reader

In my Ionic app?

Comment: Check This if it Helps: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/qr-scanner

Comment: No dude QR Scanner for Ionic is already available but , But if i see any native app like above link  how can i add that in my ionic app?

Comment: You can't merge native app into Ionic app. if you want to use any feature from that app make a plugin and use it in your app.

Comment: Can you guide me and all other to make a plugin and use it in my ionic app.

Comment: i never did this. Check the docs: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/hybrid/plugins/index.html